# Include a QR generated and hosted on google sheets in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, qr-code

I have a Google spreadsheet with some data that will generate a QR code with information and on the other hand I have a google docs template from which I would like to be able to retrieve the QR code but using "body.replaceText" does not work for me and it does not work how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much to all

Comment: Is there an insert image?

Comment: From what I understood, you want to replace a text for the QR image in a Google Doc template? Please provide the piece of code where you're trying to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function createQRCode() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.openById('Spreadsheet Id');
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var qrcode=sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var url="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" + qrcode
  var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // Get the image of QR code
  body.getChild(0).asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, resp.getBlob());
}
```

I found pretty much the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43909469/7215091)

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I have made it work.